# Best way to include different languages into a webpage

Tags: php, html

I would like to include a language menu on the top of my webpage where you can select between the languages `English (en)`, `Spanish (es)` and `German (de)` *(More languages might be added in the future)*. My website consists of the three pages `nav.php`, `index.php` and `faq.php`.

However, I am not sure about the best way to implement the languages on my website. So far I have come up with the following options:

---

**(1)** Create every page of the website in a different language and put it in the **same** folder:

```
website/pages/nav-en.php
             /nav-es.php
             /nav-de.php
             /index-en.php
             /index-es.php
             ...
```

**(2)** Create every page of the website in a different language and create an **own** folder for each language:

```
website/en/nav-en.php
          /index-en.php
          /faq-en.php

website/es/nav-es.php
          /index-es.php
          /faq-es.php

....
```

**(3)** With the options **(1)** and **(2)** described above I see the issue that code changes have to be done for each of the pages manually. Therefore, my solution would be to divide the `functional` **code** from the `text` **content** and loading the text file depending on the language that is selected in the menu:

```
website/pages/nav.php
             /index.php
             /faq.php

website/text-content/nav-text-en.php
                    /nav-text-es.php
                    /nav-text-de.php
                    /index-text-en.php
                    /index-text-es.php
                    ....
```

---

Since I am a newbie in webdeveloping I wanted to ask you:

**(a)** Are the options described above the only once or is there another (better) way to include different languages on a webpage?

**(b)** Based on your experiences which option would you recommend?

**(c)** Is there anything else I need to consider?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-i18n-internationalization-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) for translation. This way you can have one file with structure and text in the same place for all languages, and translate your strings with an editor (like poedit), which could also be done by a translator. The translator would then only see the strings in one language and have to fill in the translated version, without having to deal with the HTML around it.

There is a shortcut to the `gettext()` function, `_()`, so you can write something like

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><?=_("Linktext in different languages")?></a>
```

It's a bit more work to setup once, but after that, adding additional languages will be a lot easier than having different files with all the structure included, which will quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

*(a) Are the options described above the only once or is there another (better) way to include different languages on a webpage?*

I think using a $_GET param for both language and content is better way. For example,

```
index.php?page=faq&lang=en
```

*(b) Based on your experiences which option would you recommend?*

Using the power of php language is my advice. You may forget about static HTML website architecture.

*(c) Is there anything else I need to consider?*

If you're using apache, I suggest to use mod_rewrite. This way each page URL looks better:

```
index.php/en/faq
```

instead of

```
index.php?page=faq&lang=en
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you google at localization for PHP you will come up with multiple idea's. Personally I would use [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php). This way you can also format the numbers in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

My experience so far:

It's a nightmare to improve or even maintain a webpage where different views of the same content are based on different files, e.g. your start-page in english, german and spanish.

Therefore, it is a good approach to decouple the HTML-frame (+ CSS) from the language-dependent text. You can do that by implementing your own ideas ... or you are looking for a php framework which provides such functionality. I'm mainly a Java-guy so I don't know such framework. I guess Laravel and Zend Framework 2 could provide localization. Like others mentioned in the thread gettext also looks like a good way to realize localization in your project.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To build a multilangage website with easy maintenance, you can do this way :

**1.** You create ONE file by langage

```
en.php // english content
es.php // spanish content
...
```

**2.** Each file is an array with the same key, that content ALL the content you need to translate :

```
<?php 
// en.php

$translate = array(
    "menu_content" => array(
        "home" => "Home page",
        "nav" => "Nav page",
        ...
    ),
    "nav_page_content" => array(
        "title" => "Welcome to the nav page",
        "content" => "In this page you will find...",
        ...
    ),
    // same for ALL the content
);
```

**3.** Now, I see 2 ways you can add the content of your translation file in your website :

**3.1** : You use `$_SESSION['lang']` variable or some `$_GET['lang']` variable if you have the current langage in your URL `(eg. http://www.my-page?lang=en)` and you load the php file you need at the begin of your PHP script. Then in your HTML you get the content according to your php array (the same key in ALL langage). For example using my example array for the menu :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="home"> <?= $translate["menu_content"]["home"]; ?> </li>
        <li id="nav"> <?= $translate["menu_content"]["nav"]; ?> </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And to change langage, you create a list of your langage and on click you change the `$_SESSION['lang']` or `$_GET['lang']` value and reload your page with the new php langage content.

**3.2** : You can do almost the same without reload the page using $.ajax. The idea is almost the same : you have a list of all the langage of your website with a langage attribute for example :

```
<ul>
    <li data-lg='es'>ES</li>
    <li data-lg='en'>EN</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

On click, you you get this `data-lg` value and send it to your Ajax function, calling the php file of the choosen langage :

```
function changeLangue(lg) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: lg +".php", // eg. es.php, en.php, etc.
        dataType: "json", // you will need to add "echo json_encode($translate);" at the end of your php file to send back JSON content
        success: function(response){
             // Here your change the content of your website without reloading the page, eg with my nav before:

           $("#home").html(response.menu['home']);
           $("#nav").html(response.menu['nav']);
           ...

        },
        error:    function(x,e,t){
            manageError(x,e);
        }
    });
```

With this method, you will need to change your current langage and rebuild your langage selection too but it's not that hard in JS/jQuery.

I don't know if it's the best way to do it to be honnest but it should work (I did it with the second method to test) and it's easy to add a new langage, you will only have to :

1. Create a new php file `yournewlangage.php` with the same array than before and translate the content
2. Add the `yournewlangage` to your langage list selection

And that's all if you did it right !

An other idea could be to use a Framework for you website. For example, I'm using Silex right now (micro-framework php), it's like Symfony but lighter and you can use the translation component to help you : https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/translation.html

Framework can help you to win some time if you can use them, take some time to use the best one for what you want to do !

Hope it's clear enought and it helps a little